# JQuery Generated Table is Not Accessible to DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am generating a table based on JSON content using JQuery but when I initialize DataTables, it doesn't see the table content. What is it that I am not seeing or doing wrong?

#### HTML Code

```
<textarea id="source-code" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea><br/>
<button id="process-source">Parse JSON</button>
<div id="output-pairs"></div>
```

#### JQuery Code (updated working)

```
var sourceCode;

this.$ = this.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);

$("#process-source").click(function(){
    sourceCode = $("#source-code").val();
    $("#source-code").hide();
    $(this).hide();
    loadJSON();
    $('#nsp').DataTable( {
        "bSort": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info": true,
        "paging": true,
        "aoColumns": [ 
          { sWidth: "20%", bSearchable: true, bSortable: false }, 
          { sWidth: "40%", bSearchable: true, bSortable: false },
          { sWidth: "40%", bSearchable: true, bSortable: false }
        ],
    });
});

function loadJSON() {
    var json = $.parseJSON(sourceCode);

    var html = "<table id='nsp' class='display' data-order='[[ 1, \"asc\" ]]' data-page-length='25'>";    
    html += "<thead><tr><th colspan='2' id='banner'><span id='productName'>PRODUCT</span> <span id='versionNo'>Version " + json.V + "</span></th></tr>";
    html += "<tr><th>Settings</th><th>Values</th><th>Comments</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

    $.each(json.prefs, function (key, value) {
        html += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + value + "</td><td></td></tr>";
    });

    $.each(json, function (key, value) {
        if (key !== "prefs") {
            html += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + value + "</td><td></td></tr>";
        }
    });

    html += "</tbody></table>";

    $("#output-pairs").append(html);   
};
```

#### Result

[image]
Followed by the generated table. Based simply on the order of appearance (BLANK DataTable and then TABLE Generated) I am thinking its a order issue, but in actuality I don't think that's what's happening. I feel that somehow it has no access to the DOM content generated by the JQuery code.

Has anyone dealt with this or can tell me what I am doing wrong?

---

#### Working Result (thank you @Gyrocode)

The banner modified to `colspan='3'` actually worked luckily.

[image]

Comment: What is 'sourceCode'? It's undefined.

Comment: It is define just wasn't relevant to the issue but I will put it in there none the less.

Comment: I don't see the <tbody> anywhere.

Comment: I am pretty sure its not explicitly required to have a tbody. Plus, as I said, the table renders fine, its just not being seen as a DOM source for the DataTable.

Comment: how does your JSON looks like?

Comment: JSON is valid, correct and parses just fine and I can't share it, plus its not relevant to the issue, the issue is that a properly generated table is not accessible by the DataTable, the rest is working foundation that is not at issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

- jQuery DataTables requires `<tbody>` tag to be present when using HTML sourced data, see [HTML markup](http://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML).
- jQuery DataTables doesn't support `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes for data rows.
- You're using `append()` with not properly formed HTML elements. Construct your markup in a variable and use `append()` or `html()` then.

> **SOLUTION**

```js
function loadJSON() {
    var json = $.parseJSON(sourceCode);

    var html = "<table id='nsp' class='display' data-order='[[ 1, \"asc\" ]]' data-page-length='25'>";    
    html += "<thead><tr><th colspan='2' id='banner'><span id='productName'>PRODUCT</span> <span id='versionNo'>Version " + json.V + "</span></th></tr>";
    html += "<tr><th>Settings</th><th>Values</th><th>Comments</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

    $.each(json.prefs, function (key, value) {
        html += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + value + "</td><td></td></tr>";
    });

    $.each(json, function (key, value) {
        if (key !== "prefs") {
            html += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + value + "</td><td></td></tr>";
        }
    });

    html += "</tbody></table>";

    $("#output-pairs").append(html);   
};
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3sgr0kqs/) for demonstration.

Comment: Actually while its not in the above code, I did add the <tbody> based on DataTables recommendation, still the same result. I am going to update the code above to reflect that, I did it while I continued to try and resolve this while waiting. The DataTables still renders with "No data available in table" as seen in the picture above.

Comment: I have updated the above to reflect the current incarnation of the code. The `rowspan` was already removed, the `tbody` was already added and still nothing is showing up in the DataTables *banging head*

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that appending them would not be considered valid since the DOM inspection through the DevTools shows proper structure, but I will do it your way and see how it goes. Thank you for the DEMO as well, I appreciate it, let me implement it and I will let you know how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: Also for the record, DataTables DOES support `rowspan` and `colspan` for complex headers, see here: http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ, it doesn't support `rowspan` and `colspan` for table body (data rows), you had it in your original question. I know that it supports `rowspan` and `colspan` for table header, that is why I left it in my answer.

Comment: Since I had only used it in my header section, I wasn't sure what you were referring to but now I know you meant in the body, got it. Originally I wanted to add a `rowspan` so that I cold have a `colspan` inside it for the comments to appear below each row, but decided against it and went with adding the third column instead for that and just used it in the header to create the "banner". Thanks anyway for your help, I do appreciate you helping me get it working. I can't believe that `append()` and `html()` work so drastically different in terms of DOM.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do to debug or implement a Databable is create a proper table structure with static data. That way you would realise that the problem is much simpler: DataTables is not the issue but the table structure created by jQuery.

You are using append to 'append' chunks of html inside your #output-pairs container. This is doing that the first append in your loadJSON function is appending a whole element, this is, it's closing your table before even putting any content in it. The rest of your appends are being added to the body, not to the table.

The solution is create your table in a variable and then use this to insert the html content in your container.

```
 function loadJSON(){
     var o = $("#output-pairs");   
     var html = "<table id='nsp' class='display' data-order='[[ 1, \"asc\" ]]' data-page-length='25'>";
     var json = $.parseJSON(sourceCode);

     html += "<thead>";
     html += "<tr><th colspan='2' id='banner'><span id='productName'>PRODUCT</span> <span id='versionNo'>Version " + json.V + "</span></th></tr>";
     html += "<tr><th>Settings</th><th>Values</th><th>Comments</th></tr>"          
     html += "</thead><tbody>";

     $.each( json.prefs, function( key, value ) {
        html += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + value + "</td><td></td></tr>";
     });

     $.each( json, function( key, value ) {
        if (key !== "prefs"){
            html += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + value + "</td><td></td></tr>";
        }
    });
    html += "</tbody></table>";

o.html(html);
```

};

Also note that your head wasn't properly formed as the tr weren't closed. I have closed them here for you.

In regards to your second $.each I think there is something wrong there as well. Don't you think it would be better to create an array with you pairs key-value instead using and 'if' to skip your prefs?

I would use an structure like: json.version, json.settings, json.values, ... So in your second each you can just iterate over json.values.

Comment: I did test with static code, it works but that's not what I needed, I need it to work with onfly generated content and so here we are. Thank you for the assist.

Comment: What I meant is for only testing. Have you tried my solution with your Json? I tested with something like {"V":"1.0","prefs":[{"pref1":"value1", "pref2": "value2"}]} and it worked perfectly;

Comment: Yeah the values were not the issue, it got resolved, thank you for your help.